# Why Mac users don't see me online when I use MSN through empathy?

Tags: empathy

Why Macintosh users don't see me online when I use MSN through empathy?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You should probably take a look and see if they can see you when you're online with another chat service (such as google talk) - it's entirely possible that it's a MSN server side problem, in which case Empathy isn't at fault.

Comment: No, it is an Empathy problem, because when I use MSN through aMSN, Emesene and Kmess they are able to see me online and chat with me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Pidgin or Kopete instead of Empathy. If it works there, submit a bug report to: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/ on the Empathy section.